# How to avoid Case Sensitive Contains check in formula field

Tags: formula-field, contains

I have one formula field where I have used condition

`IF(CONTAINS(Title, "Chief Architect"),"Architect")`

So whenever I enter title `Chief Architect` the formula field appear as `Architect`

My issue is if someone enters Chief as `chief Architect`, `cHief Architect` or `Chief architect`.
It wont populate I want to cover these all scenarios what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `LOWER` [function](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) as follows.

```
 IF(CONTAINS(LOWER(Title), "chief architect"),"Architect")
```